# How to align UIImageView to the centre of the view controller?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I want an imageview to appear centre at the bottom,i added the imageview to another imageview in the view controller.the result is imageview is appearing at the bottom but not exactly at centre, can any one suggest what is wrong in my code?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

    [imgView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


    UIImageView *mspimgvw=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

    [mspimgvw setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    mspimgvw.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"msplogo.jpg"];

    [self.imgView addSubview:mspimgvw];

    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    CGFloat bottom=0;
    [imgView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mspimgvw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:bottom-40]];

    [imgView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mspimgvw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:bottom-40]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imgView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:dicViews]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imgView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:dicViews]];
}
```

I want image to appear to the centre of the view controller.What to change in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.f
                                                       constant:0.f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.f
                                                       constant:0.f]];
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me!As well as need to add attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom to make the uiimageview to appear at bottom.

Comment: Yes you're right, edited the answer so you can accept it now. :)

Comment: can u suggest how to implement auto layout for UITabBar,if i add constraint i can’t see the horizontal line of the tab bar.my code is

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tabbarObj attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];

Comment: I usually add my constraints using the IB, so I can't really help you with that, sorry!